# Conditional retry advice in a Spring Integration message flow?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a http gateway call that's occasionally returning 503 errors.  I'd like to configure [retry advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#advice-classes) around that call, but I don't want to do it for every error, just the 503s.

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway ... errorHandler="...">
    <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice max-attempts="3" />
    </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

I already have a custom error handler configured that filters statuses (ex: 404) that I don't want to treat as errors, but I don't see an obvious way to control how the advice is applied based on what I can do in the error handler.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236216/is-it-possible-to-set-retrypolicy-in-spring-retry-based-on-httpstatus-status-cod) deals with the same issue, but the answer doesn't explain how to control the advice behavior or reissue the request at the error handler level.  Is there a specific exception type to throw?

edit: Example based on answer:

```
<bean id="spelParser" class="org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway ...>
    <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
            <property name="retryTemplate">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
                    <property name="retryPolicy">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.ExpressionRetryPolicy">
                            <constructor-arg index="0" type="org.springframework.expression.Expression" value="#{spelParser.parseExpression('cause.statusCode.value() == 503')}" />
                            <property name="maxAttempts" value="3" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="backOffPolicy">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                            <property name="initialInterval" value="1000" />
                            <property name="multiplier" value="2" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for the case when you have a `HttpServerErrorException` but would like to distinguish it by the `statusCode` from others and don't retry, I would suggest to take a look into the:

```
 * Subclass of {@link SimpleRetryPolicy} that delegates to super.canRetry() and,
 * if true, further evaluates an expression against the last thrown exception.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 1.2
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ExpressionRetryPolicy extends SimpleRetryPolicy implements BeanFactoryAware {
```

Where your expression can be like:

```
expression="statusCode.value() == 503"
```

**UPDATE**

Ah! I see. Since `ExpressionRetryPolicy` uses `TemplateParserContext` your expression definitely must be like `#{statusCode.value() == 503}`. But at the same time it is going to be evaluate during bean factory initialization. I suggest you to do something like this:

```
<bean id="spelParser" class="org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser"/>
```

and in the `ExpressionRetryPolicy` bean definition do:

```
<constructor-arg index="0" type="org.springframework.expression.Expression" 
                 value="#{spelParser.parseExpression('statusCode.value() == 503')}" />
```

To overcome the collision.

Comment: To customize the policy, you supply the advice as a `<bean/>` (`RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`), injecting a custom `RetryTemplate` with the custom policy.

Comment: I think I see how to wire up ExpressionRetryPolicy.  (I had to pull in that dependency separately because spring-integration:4.3.12.RELEASE only grabs spring-retry:1.1.x instead of the new 1.2 version where that class was introduced.)  However, I'm getting an error at startup because it can't resolve the expression.  (`EL1008E: Property or field '$statusCode' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?`) The SPEL I tried is `expression="#{$statusCode.value() == 503}"`.

Comment: ??? That's not SpEL. You have to specify `runtime expression`. And I told you already how: `expression="statusCode.value() == 503"`. What you try to do is called `bean factory initialization expression`, but really not runtime. Anyway the `$` symbol is wrong too...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I started mangling the expression in response to the errors I was getting.  I've edited my question to show the XML I'm using.  When I give it the expression as you described, I get a runtime error about how the result is string instead of boolean.  When I debug, I see that the expression has been parsed as a string literal.  Am I completely off track here, or is there something different I need to do with the ExpressionRetryPolicy?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: It works!  I had to insert "cause." at the front of the expression because there's a MessageHandlingException wrapper around the HttpServerErrorException, but I was able to verify that 500s failed immediately and 503s were retried.  Thanks Artem and Gary for the explanations.  This will no doubt be a lot smoother in a future release of SI.

Comment: I raised an issue for Spring Retry: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/89

Comment: @NathanWilliams how did you verify 500s are failing immediately and 503s are getting retried

Comment: That's what the `RetryPolicy` is for, @MouleshKumar - `canRetry()` is `boolean` to fail or retry.

Comment: I temporarily changed the application that my integration configuration was targeting to return those statuses.  Alternatively you could change the URL to an external test site like https://httpstat.us/503